# How to generate random values in google sheets with a dynamic output range?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to generate random values in a range of cells with randbetween(cell1, cell2). The range is 12 columns wide and the number of rows are based on an input value (cell3 in my example). In the body I have written my formula, but it does not generate the random numbers I had expected. Can anyone point out my mistake?

=array_constrain(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    {A2:A} + randbetween(cell1,cell2)
  ),
  cell3, 12
)

I am getting
[image]

And I am trying to build this:
[image]

Comment: What is the sample input, current result, and the expected result?

Comment: Please edit that into the question

Comment: Yeah, sorry. So basically, I want my users to answer the question is the yellow box. I only need to solve the first part: how many rows (shops) do you want, and how many beds (randombetween) do you expect to sell.

Comment: @Andreas do you see what I am doing wrong?